# Functional way of re-using variables in a pipe

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Using functional programming in javascript and typescript together with Ramda, I often find myself writing code like:

```
const myFun = c => {
  const myId = c.id

  const value = pipe(
    getAnotherOtherPropOfC,
    transformToArray,
    mapToSomething,
    filterSomething,
    // ... N other transformations
    // ok now I need myId and also the result of the previous function
    chainMyIdWithResultOfPreviousFunction(myId)
  )(c)

  return value
}
```

Notice how creating a `const myId` breaks point-free style. I'd like to write `myFun` so that there's no need to explicit `c`. So something like: 
`const myFun = pipe(....)`

I was wondering if there's a more functional and readable way of doing things like this.

Comment: Using a variable multiple time is *much* easier and readable without pointfree style.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with a second input? I.e. `const myFun = (c, id) => {...}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Can* it be done?  Sure.  *Should* it be done?  It's not so clear.

Here is a point-free version of the above, using `lift`:

```js
const getAnotherOtherPropOfC = prop ('x')
const transformToArray = split (/,\s*/)
const mapToSomething = map (Number)
const filterSomething = filter (n => n % 2 == 1)
const square = (n) => n * n
const chainMyIdWithResultOfPreviousFunction = (id) => (arr) => `${id}: [${arr}]`

const myFun = lift (chainMyIdWithResultOfPreviousFunction) (
  prop ('id'),
  pipe(
    getAnotherOtherPropOfC,
    transformToArray,
    mapToSomething,
    filterSomething,
    map (square)
  )
)

console .log (
  myFun ({id: 'foo', x: '1, 2, 3, 4, 5'}) // => 'foo: [1,9,25]'
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {prop, split, map, filter, lift, pipe} = R            </script>
```

[`lift`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lift) is a more FP-standard function than Ramda's [`converge`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge) (which together with [`useWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#useWith) offer ways to make point-free solutions, often at the expense of readability.)  `lift` overlaps with `converge` when applied to functions, but is designed for unary functions, where `converge` handles polyadic ones.

This is not horrible.  But the only advantage it has over the original is that it's point-free.  And if you were to try to extend this to intermediate functions in that pipeline, it would get downright ugly.

My take is that point-free can at times lead to cleaner, easier-to-read, and easier-to-maintain code.  But there is no reason to go point-free when it doesn't do so.

It's not that point-free is inherently more functional than pointed code.  I think this idea starts as a sort of Haskell-envy from other languages.  Haskell is held up as an idealized FP language, and it happens to be a language in which point-free comes naturally.  But that's at least partially coincidental.

My standard example is that `const sum = reduce(add, 0)` is cleaner and more comprehensible than `const sum = (xs) => xs.reduce(add, 0)`.  It also makes extremely clear the parallels with `const product = reduce(multiply, 1)` or `const all = reduce(and, true)`.  But as you get more complex, or when you need to reuse an intermediate calculation (as Bergi pointed out), point-free code often becomes a liability.

I don't have a real call here about whether this version is an improvement on the original.  If so, it's only a minor one.  Carrying it further would significantly degrade the readability.

Answer (score 2):

Variables are usually an indication that your function is doing too much and should be decomposed. For example, this

```
const myFun = c => {
    let id = c.id;

    return R.pipe(
        R.prop('list'),
        R.map(R.add(10)),
        R.sum,
        R.subtract(id),
    )(c)
}
```

can be refactored into two separate functions:

```
const compute = R.pipe(
    R.prop('list'),
    R.map(R.add(10)),
    R.sum,
);

const getId = R.prop('id');
```

and then simply

```
const myFun = c => getId(c) - compute(c)
```

which looks good enough to me, but if you want to be absolutely point-free, then

```
const myFun = R.converge(R.subtract, [getId, compute])
```

[Playground](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?const%20myFun1%20%3D%20c%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20id%20%3D%20c.id%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20R.pipe%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20R.prop%28%27list%27%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20R.map%28R.add%2810%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20R.sum%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20R.subtract%28id%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%29%28c%29%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20compute%20%3D%20R.pipe%28%0A%20%20%20%20R.prop%28%27list%27%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20R.map%28R.add%2810%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20R.sum%2C%0A%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20getId%20%3D%20R.prop%28%27id%27%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20myFun2%20%3D%20c%20%3D%3E%20getId%28c%29%20-%20compute%28c%29%0A%0Aconst%20myFun3%20%3D%20R.converge%28R.subtract%2C%20%5BgetId%2C%20compute%5D%29%0A%0A%2F%2F%0A%0Alet%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%2092%2C%0A%20%20%20%20list%3A%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%5D%0A%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Aconsole.log%28myFun1%28obj%29%29%0Aconsole.log%28myFun2%28obj%29%29%0Aconsole.log%28myFun3%28obj%29%29)

Comment: I like this approach. I didn't know about the `converge` function so thanks! I'm still wondering if this pattern covers the majority of the cases in which I need to reuse variables in a pipe. What if `R.subtract(id)` and `R.sum` are switched in the original `myFun`? (meaning that `id` is not used in the last function of the pipe, but in the middle of it, and potentially reused N times more inside the pipe)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I use vanilla JS to reach a wider audiance.

A `pipe` is just a composite function is just a function. So let's use a higher order pipe that takes a pipe, a function and a value and returns another function instead of the result. To actually get the result we need to pass the value twice:

```js
const toUc = s => s.toUpperCase();
const double = s => `${s}${s}`;
const shout = s => `${s}!`;
const concat = t => s => `${s} -> ${t}`;

const pipe = g => f => x => f(g(x));
const pipe3 = h => g => f => x => f(g(h(x)));

const foo = {id: "hi"};
const bar = pipe3(toUc) (shout) (double); // pipe

const baz = pipe(bar) (concat); // higher order pipe

// the result of the applied pipe is just another function because concat requires two arguments!

console.log(
  baz(foo.id)) // s => `${s} -> ${t}`

// let's apply it twice

console.log(
  baz(foo.id)
    (foo.id)); // hi -> HI!HI!
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```js
const getAnotherPropOfC = R.prop('message');
const transformToArray = R.split('');
const mapToSomething = R.map(R.toUpper);
const filterSomething = R.reject(R.equals(' '));
const chainMyIdWithResultOfPreviousFunction = R.pipe(
  R.prop('fragment'), 
  R.concat,
);

const myFun = R.converge(R.map, [
  chainMyIdWithResultOfPreviousFunction,
  R.pipe(
    getAnotherPropOfC,
    transformToArray,
    mapToSomething,
    filterSomething,
  ),
]);



console.log(
  myFun({ message: 'Hello World', fragment: '!' }),
);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```