# How to access two parameter in functional programming

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have a pipe like this

```
pipe(
    getUserData,
    getLocationData,
    someFunctionThatNeedBothUserAndLocationData
)(input)
```

I need to have a function that access to both user and location data like this

```
function someFunctionThatNeedBothUserAndLocationData(user, location){
    // do something
}
```

How can I do something like that in functional programming?

Comment: Just don't use `pipe`. It's still functional programming when calling functions directly…

Comment: "functional" doesn't necessarily mean "point-free", see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58203072/989121

Comment: This seems to be applicative lifting in the function context: `const liftA2 = f => g => h => x => f(g(x)) (h(x))`.

Comment: Please notice that piping is just upside down function composition, which in turn is a functorial computation, i.e. an applied functor of the function type. FP consists of much more than just the functor instance of pure functions.

Answer (score 2):

not really possible with `pipe`, since subsequent functions are unary (they take as argument the result of a previous function). A **converge** function helps here I think!

```js
const log = (user, location) => {
  console.log(`${user.name} is in ${location}`);
};


const getUserData = () => ({ name: 'Giuseppe' });
const getUserLocation = () => 'Bologna';

R.converge(log, [
  getUserData,
  getUserLocation,
])();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-xB25ljGZ7K2VXnq087unEnoVhvTosWWtqXB4tAtZmHU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not too late.

```
const pipedFunction = pipe(
    getUserData,
    getLocationData,
    someFunctionThatNeedBothUserAndLocationData
)(input)

const getLocationData = (userData) => [user, location]

const someFunctionThatNeedBothUserAndLocationData = (arg) => {
  const [user, location] = arg;
}
```

or

```
const pipedFunction = pipe(
    getUserData,
    getLocationData,
    someFunctionThatNeedBothUserAndLocationData
)(input)

const getLocationData = (userData) => {user, location}

const someFunctionThatNeedBothUserAndLocationData = (arg) => {
  const {user, location} = arg;
}
```